# OpenCV cannot stream IP camera

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, ip-camera

I'm using the below code to access an IP camera, but I keep getting an error. If I change ip address to "1" which is a USB connected webcam, everything works fine, but streaming from URL doesn't work. I can access the camera from browser without any issues. I'm using OpenCV v3.1.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture ip_cam = new VideoCapture();

    ip_cam.open("http://192.168.1.9:8080/video?x.mjpeg");

    if (!ip_cam.isOpened())
    {
        System.out.print("Error");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Success");

    ip_cam.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version of OpenCV I was using, even though it is the latest version, it still has issues streaming from a URL, v2.4.9 works just fine.